# Migrating InfoPath Form from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-forms-services

We're migrating a very complicated Infopath template from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online. This template requires domain permissions and a lot of custom code, so a browser-enabled form is not possible.

In Sharepoint 2013, we share the template file (.xsn) which people can click on and it will open in InfoPath Form Filler, where they can do their work. Nobody actually submits the form, because the data is kept on a database.

In Sharepoint Online, the .xsn file will open in Designer view. This is an issue because the users are non-technical people and we don't want them to have to click through to preview or accidentally change something.

We've published the form in a Form Library, but when someone tries to create a new Form, it'll open correctly in InfoPath Filler Form, but give an XML error.

"The form contains XML that cannot be parsed: An invalid character was found in text content. Line 1, Position 5 MSCF"

When I check out the underlying template, I can Edit the Template, which again opens up InfoPath Designer with no issues.

I've also exported out the XML for the template and spot no XML errors and can open it in InfoPath designer, so I'm at a loss about how to debug the XML error.

So, we can go either route to resolve the issue:

1) Continue putting the template file on the Sharepoint folders and having users click on it and fill in data, but it must open in Filler Form, not Designer.

2) Fix the issue with the XML Form error (how do I go about even debugging this?) I've exported out the template as a .XML file, but can not spot any XML errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Update, I'm getting a separate error after publishing again to a Form Library:

"DTD is prohibited"

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to get rid of infopath and use a custom form using javascript in classic UI mode OR develop an SPFX webpart that achieve the same thing as your infopath ?

Comment: That's the future implementation; we're going full custom UI .Net application. We're looking for a short-term fix before that product launches.